# how to #include third party libraries

Tags: c++, build, include, libraries, include-path

I have built and installed a library called [OhNet](http://wiki.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet). After `make install` the corresponding header files of the framework have been installed under `usr/local/include/ohNet`. Now I want to use the Library in my C++ project (i am using eclipse) but when i try to include some header files, eclipse is not able to find the files.
As far as i know eclipse should search for header files in these directories (/usr/include , /usr/local/include ,...) by default.... What do i have to do to use the library? 
I am pretty new to C++ and haven't used third party sources before.

Thank you.

--EDIT--
I simply want to write an easy "helloworld" programm to verify that i have included the framework correctly. In order to do that i want to instatiate the class `OpenHome::Net::DvDeviceStdStandard`. see: [ohNet C++ reference](http://www.openhome.org/build/nightly/docs/CppStd/)

I can now include the header file using:
`#include <ohNet/OpenHome/Net/Core/DvDevice.h>` That works fine. But how can i create an object of type `OpenHome::Net::DvDeviceStdStandard` ? now? Eclipse says that this type cannot be resolved. :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ohNet/OpenHome/Net/Core/DvDevice.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    OpenHome::Net::DvDeviceStdStandard device; //type cannot be resolved
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a short, complete example, along with the compiler error? In particular, I'm interested in the `#include` directive you are using which fails.

Comment: #include < path as if working directory is usr/local/include >

Comment: If just Eclipse says so, but your project compiles without error, try re-indexing the project.

Comment: Thank you for you help. It works. I also marked your answer as accepted! :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Use the `-I` compiler option to point to the 3rd party libraries directory (`-I/usr/local/include/ohNet`)
2. Use `#include "[whatever you need from oHNet].h"` in your header files and compilation units as needed (**Note:** you might need to put relative prefix pathes for subdirecories in the 3rd party include paths tree here!)
3. Use the `-L` linker option to specify a path to the 3rd party libs you need (`-L/usr/local/lib` probably)
4. Use the `-l` linker option to specify any concrete 3rd libs you need (`-l[oHNet]` probably)

Look in the directories what actually was installed there to figure what to place for `[whatever you need from oHNet].h` and `[oHNet]`, s.th. like `liboHNet.a` for the latter.

You didn't tag [tag:Eclipse CDT] explicitly here, but go to the Project->Properties->C++ Builder->Settings Dialog and look for C/C++ Includes and Linker Options.

Comment: thx, i'll try that. but to clarify: It's NOT true that the c++ compiler will recognize per default any header files in /usr/include, /usr/local/include, /usr/lib, etc... ? I always have to link the libraries with the -I compiler option?

Comment: @user1291235 As Benjamin Lindley already mentioned it may depend on how you're specifying the `#include` statement. So show what you're doing in more detail please.

Comment: @user1291235 And yes, it is true, but the compiler linker doesn't look up recursively there.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put the header files that you want to use, in your project folder and then use #include in your .cpp file just like how you would do for any other header files.

Comment: why copy? it's only needed to tell the compiler where to look for the files (by using `-I` with `g++` as an example)

Comment: Actually i installed the library using `make install` and all the files where copied to `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`, so i guess i do not have to put those files into the project?!