# Connecting the Raspberry Pi 2 with an External Remote Database

Tags: c++, mysql, database, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I want to connect my Raspberry Pi 2 to an external MySQL database on 000webhost.com with the help of C++.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{    
try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("<000webhost mysql address>", "<username>", "<password>");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("<database>");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("<sql statement>"); // replace with your statement
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I got an error saying that the `mysql_connection.h` file was missing. I don't know what i did wrong or if there is an easier or simpler way. Please help me with this matter. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the [source installed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html) for `mysql_connection.h` to work on your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I didn't install mysql on the raspberry pi since I was trying to access an external database. I am new to the raspberry pi environment.

Comment: Note that I didn't ask of you have MySQL installed, but the source for the MySQL connector C++ library, which is not MySQL. You'll need the library, which is the same thing as a package in Python, but for C++, in order for including mysql_connection.h to work.

Answer (score 0):

> I got an error saying that the mysql_connection.h file was missing.

Going by the error message you describe and the response to my question "Do you have the source installed for `mysql_connection.h`?," which was:

> I **didn't install mysql** on the raspberry pi since I was trying to access an external database.

(*Which is not what I asked.*) it appears the reason `#include "mysql_connection.h` doesn't work is because the library isn't there.

The `Connector/C` library **does not** require the installation of MySQL, but the `Connector/C` source **must** be installed to include headers from the library, [according to the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-prerequisites.html).

MySQL's `Connector/C` library **requires** [boost](http://www.boost.org); however Raspian already has boost installed, though that may come with it's own set of issue, which are discussed and resolved [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=86084) if you have trouble with boost. (If your Raspberry Pi has NOOBS, I recommend switching to Raspian.)

Though the link is in my comments, instructions for installing the `Connector/C` library are available from [MySQL's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html).

I've collected some resources and links which should provide some additional help:

1. [How to Install Third Party Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942545/how-to-install-third-party-libraries)
2. [How to #include third party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887265/how-to-include-third-party-libraries)
3. [Installing Connector/C++ from Source on Unix and Unix-Like Systems](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-unix.html)